# DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers is returning empty array for Bouvet Island(BV) and Heard Island and McDonald Islands(HM)

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to get timezones for Bouvet Island(BV) and Heard Island and McDonald Islands(HM) with the DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers, but for both the function returns an empty array. Is there any solution for this or other way to get timezone by country code?

```
$timezoneIdentifiers = null;
if($countryCode) {
    $timezoneIdentifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, $countryCode);
} else {
    $timezoneIdentifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
}
```

Comment: And you're trying to do this *how*?

Comment: what is wrong with this question? I'm trying to get alternatives...

Comment: If you just want these two timezones, you don't need to list them from anywhere, you can just look them up once and then use the timezone hardcoded. It's unclear what issue exactly you're trying to solve, or how your attempt at solving it fails since we don't see what exactly you're attempting.

Comment: I need to get array of taimezones by country codes but for those 2 countries I get an empty array. Yes I know that I can hardcode for those 2 countries just wanted to know if there is another way to do this.

Comment: So your code is `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'HM')`?! Just give us a sample so we can confirm whether that *should* work or whether you have some dumb mistake in your code.

Comment: added in description